# Purely theoretical question about idelal filters and infinite oscillations

Tags: interpolation, sinc

I am asking perhaps a naive question, but still, it would be nice to have this formally stated one time:

in theory, if we could do it (of course, we cannot, but imagine we could), if we could convolve an upsampled image with an infinite sinc function (resulting from the ideal low-pass filter in freqency domain, i.e., the brick-wall) would the interpolation really be perfect, i.e., no Gibbs ripples ?

Comment: Wht do you mean by "upsampled image"?

Comment: I mean just the result of x_up=upsample(x,upFactor); in Matlab, given a signal x (e.g. 1D here) and an upsampling factor e.g. 2, so by upsampling I refer to the first step before actual 'interpolation' with an interpolator, like the ideal sinc interpolator to which i m referring to. (i.e.,Matlab's upsample just adds zeros in between samples to extend the signal)

Comment: I don’t think you can reformulate your question in a way that someone like Karl Popper would consider it to be a Scientific question. One could answer your question either way. There is no way to prove perfection. As an engineer, filtering is done within a real world

Comment: Your question IMHO is a philosophical one not a theoretical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: historically the Gibbs phenomenon was described over a continuous-time domain periodic square wave which was constructed from a finite number of its Fourier series coefficients, however, one can interchange the domains and observe the same behaviour on the frequency response of a finite length discrete-time filter with its impulse response samples designating the Fourier series coefficients.

This question is essentially asking the consequences of the unavoidable Gibbs phenomenon on the mathematical construction of an ideal brick-wall filter whose frequency domain definition apparently (and confusingly) does not involve the expected Gibbs ripples...?

The practical answer is that as the filter length approaches infinity the peak magnitude of the ripples does not reduce, but its duration shrinks to a single point at the edges of the passband. From Riemannian integration point of view, this will not have an effect on the filter's output as if there's no Gibbs phenomenon.

On any finite length approximation of an ideal brickwall filter, however, the ripples do exist, and will alter the actual output from that of an ideal filter's computation. The better solution to reduce those ripples is to make use of a window instead of increasing the filter impulse response truncation length.

Comment: thanks for your answer. By window are referring to something like the so-called Hamming or Kaiser window to progressively reduce the sinc ripples in the time domain?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Hello, sorry to post here but I have a very interesting question related to ML here that nobody is answering and maybe you could ... (and since its unfortunately impossible to contact ppl directly here) ... https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63277/adversarial-training-deep-learning-book